# Load and push tarball to docker registry

Tags: python, docker, python-asyncio, docker-registry

I'm currently working on a python microservice that implemtents a docker image upload (as a tarball) via the tus protocol. When the image has finished uploading, a daemon scans for finished uploads, picks up the file, does a docker load and pushes it to a private registry. The microservice/daemon are running as docker containers aswell.

So I got a few question regarding this procedure:

1. Is a docker load safe when trying to load a corrupted image or might this lead to a complete crash of the daemon? What is a pssoible scenario to prevent this?
2. What kind of automated security checks would be advisable? (e.g. docker inspect?!)
3. How can I check for an image name/tag before loading the image? Is this even possible? Or is there a way to tag the image with a custom tag when/before loading the image to my local docker registry?
4. Would it be a better way to outsource the whole loading and pushing procedure to a sealed environment? (i.e. the daemon only triggers the upload process and updates the progress)

If my workflow is somehow a bad practice, I would be very happy if you could suggest a cleaner solution to my problem or give advice on possible weak spots. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The whole process you are describing does not seem to be anywhere near a typical Docker micro-service deployment. Please explain why you went this way!

Comment: We are developing a platform where AI solutions of different vendors are deployed as containerized applications. At the moment these container images are pushed to a private docker registry manually. In the future we would like to provide an automated upload, where vendors can provide their containerized apps as tarball. This tarball should than be checked for valid tags, security issues, etc. and subsequently pushed to the registry.

Answer (score 0):

1. There could be bugs in `dockerd` that crash the daemon.
2. Depends on your use case and security stance. What would you need to check against?
3. Yes; read `manifest.json` from the tarball. For `busybox:latest` on my machine, it contains

   ```
   [{"Config":"7138284460ffa3bb.json", "RepoTags":["busybox:latest"], "Layers":["c827bfcc43098/layer.tar"]}]
   ```
4. Yes, there is: [the Skopeo tool](https://github.com/containers/skopeo) lets you push an image directly to a Docker registry without a Docker daemon. I've used it in my [pino](https://github.com/akx/pino) tool; you can find usage tips there.